# Convert string to be used as a column name in Oracle

Tags: string, oracle

I want to use convert a column name to string or vice versa. I need it for a query that I run in an EMM suite named Unica (IBM Experience One).

I have a string i.e. 'CL_CREDIT_LIMIT' that I need to use it in a query as a string to populate a table (using CASE) and also I need to use as a column name. Both in the same query.

More specifically, I pass this value to a Macro(in Unica) but only once (either as string (with ' ') or as column name). So I just need a way to convert these into each other and it doesn't matter which one to which but preferably column name to string.

I would like to know if there's a

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you're trying to do. As the question stands I'm not clear on your intentions. Are you attempting to pass a string variable to an SQL statement where the contents of the variable are treated as a column name? If so, that won't work. You may want to investigate [how to use dynamic SQL in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011). Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question Bob. It's an Oracle+Unica issue that I have.  
I put it this way maybe it makes it clear:  
I have a query that a parameter (or a token) is passed to it. This parameter is a table name for which I can choose a type. If I put it as none (it's a Unica thing) and the query will treat it as a name like a column name (without '  ') and it can be used in a statement like " SELECT MyParamater FROM MY_TABLE" .

Comment: In the same query I want to use MyPramater as a string something like: " SELECT X FROM Y WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'MyParameter' "  So I can only pass the parameter as String or None and I need to use it as both so I need to convert it from string to none or from none to string.it doesn't matter which.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to build a query dynamically and then execute it. Perhaps the following will give you some ideas:

```
DECLARE
  strQuery       VARCHAR2(32767);
  strColumn_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'CL_CREDIT_LIMIT';
  cCursor        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  nColumn_value  NUMBER;
  strVal2        VARCHAR2(32767);
  dtVal3         DATE;
BEGIN
  strQuery := 'SELECT ' || strColumn_name || ', FIELD2, FIELD3 ' ||
              'FROM SOME_TABLE ' ||
                'WHERE ' || strColumn_name || ' > 10000';

  OPEN cCursor FOR strQuery;

  LOOP
    FETCH cCursor
      INTO nColumn_value, strVal2, dtVal3;
    EXIT WHEN cCursor%NOTFOUND;

    -- Do something with the fetched values - for example...

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(strColumn_name || '=' || nColumn_value ||
                         '  FIELD2=''' || strVal2 || '''' ||
                         '  FIELD3=' || TO_CHAR(dtVal3, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE SOME_OTHER_TABLE ' ||
                      'SET SOME_COLUMN = ' ||
                        'CASE '
                          'WHEN ' || strColumn_name || ' = ''CL_CREDIT_LIMIT'' THEN 123 ' ||
                          'WHEN ' || strColumn_name || ' = ''CL_OTHER'' THEN 456 ' ||
                          'ELSE 789 '
                         'END '
                      'WHEN KEY_COLUMN = ''SOMETHING OR OTHER''';
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cCursor;
END;
```